# OCUnit and C++ in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Is anybody using OCUnit (as in Xcode 4.2 Unit Testing) with C++ code successfully?

After hours trying to understand what's going on I'm now pretty convinced there are some major flaws in using Xcode 4 and OCUnit to test C++ code from Objective-C++ files (.mm)

The main application (Cocoa with some C++ business logic) compiles fine!
The trivial .mm test class fails with weird compiler errors, varying between

- Use of undeclared identifier (C++ class name)
- Use of incomplete type
- C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

and so forth. Basically it seems to be terribly confused with the C++ bits.
The classes the test files complain about compile JUST FINE from the main application!
They can be instantiated in the main application JUST FINE.

Anybody having encountered and solved this before?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 3):

When I unit tested C++ code with OCUnit, I had to make the C++ implementation files members of the unit test target to get unit tests to work. Select a C++ file from the project navigator and open the file inspector. There should be a Target Membership section in the file inspector. The Target Membership section has a list of your project's targets with a checkbox next to each target. Select the checkbox next to the unit test target to make the file a member of the unit test target.

Comment: Right - that does make sense I suppose.  
However I was using my main application as 'Test Host' and set it as 'Bundle Loaded' in the Linking prefs as well.  
My understandig of the Xcode 4 unit testing is that this should allow single compilation of sources but makes them available in the unit test target at the same time.

Comment: The way you set things up should work for Objective-C code. It's C++ code where problems occur. All I know is I get link errors when unit testing C++ code with OCUnit if the C++ files being tested aren't members of the unit test target.

Comment: Sigh! Depending on which classes I'm trying to access in the unit test class the compiler sometimes even gets that far! Yet some classes work just fine.. pretty dodgy.  I'll park the whole unit testing for now and revisit with Xcode 5..