# Unit Test C++ code in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, unit-testing, octest

I am using OCTest for Objective-C code. Does OCTest support C++? How do I go about writing tests for C++ classes?

Comment: I don't know if OCTest supports C++, but for C++ unit tests, I strongly recommend Google Test: http://code.google.com/p/googletest/

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447499/ocunit-and-c-in-xcode-4